# Composition of relations: A ∘ B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Solve: Composition of relations: A ∘ B

A = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (4, 1), (4, 2)}

B = {(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 4), (2, 4)}

When I solve mentally I get A ∘ B = {(1, 1), (2,2)}

But when I draw an arrow-diagram I get A ∘ B = {(1, 1), **(1, 2)**, **(2, 1)**, (2,2)}

**(1, 2)** and **(2, 1)** from the the arrow-diagram since 4 points to 1 & 2, and 1 also points 1 & 2.

[image]

Which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram is correct.

$B$ maps both $1$ and $2$ to $1$ or $4$.   $A$ maps both $1$ and $4$ to $1$ or $2$.

Thus $A\circ B$ maps both $1$ and $2$ to $1$ or $2$.

---

When you solved mentally, I guess you *mistook* the relations for inverses which *would* have meant the composition was an identity.   However, as neither is *one-to-one*, then they are *not* invertible.

Comment: ohhhh i seee! Thankss :)